# angular-schema-form - Custom validation message is not shown after form validation

Tags: validation, message, angular-schema-form

In my form I have the following definition for a custom validation:

```
'staff[].title': {
  key: 'staff[].title',
  validationMessage: {
    'needTitle': function() { console.log('DEBUG!'); return 'Need title';}
  },
  $validators: {
    needTitle: function (value) {
      return value ? true : false;
    }
  }
}
```

When I validate my form by **$scope.$broadcast('schemaFormValidate');** the **staff[].title** field indicates there is an error which is great, but its error message is never shown. However, if I also broadcast the event **scope.$broadcast('schemaForm.error.staff[].title,...)** only then the error message appears. The trouble with this technique is that I have to broadcast the event once more with a **true** value, **$scope.$broadcast('schemaForm.error.staff[].title,...,true)** to set the field state back to normal.

Any ideas on how to do this with just **$scope.$broadcast('schemaFormValidate');**?

The annoying part with the current I do is that I have two broadcast two events to validate the form have my custom valuation messages shown!

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I've run up against the exact same issue and can't find a solution.

Comment: Hi there, not really, somebody gave me an idea but I never followed it. I wonder if the latest version has resolved this issue. Anyways, here is the dude's repsponse: https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form/issues/602.